# Finding local min/max of a cubic function

Tags: python, math, scientific-computing

I'm looking to program a Python function that takes in 6 variables, `a, b, c, d, e, f`, where `a, b` is the interval to compute on (e.g. `[1, 3]`, all real numbers), and `c, d, e, f` are the coefficients of the cubic polynomial, i.e. `f(x) = cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f`, and returns the local min/max on the interval `[a, b]`.

I have a rough idea (although the computing time would be bad) of how to program this, where I create a new list of steps `0.01` or something similarly small from `a` to `b`, evaluate `f` at each value, then simply return the min/max of the list. This would take very long for `a, b` values that are very far apart.

What is the best way to go about making this? Are there any outside libraries for scientific/mathematical computing? Thank you.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Comment: I don't understand why you think the computing of these roots would be bad.  Certainly your idea of small steps would be slow, but using a better algorithm like Newton's method or steepest descent would make this trivial in general.  There is a closed form solution for cubics similar to quadratic equation if you're really worried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cubic function you can find positions of potential minumum/maximums without optimization but using differentiation:

- get the first and the second derivatives
- find zeros of the first derivative (solve quadratic equation)
- check the second derivative in found points - sign tells whether that point is min, max or saddle point

I think that  differentiation should be in `sympy` package

Also check whether problem statement assumes accounting for boundary values (as @Lakshay Garg notices in comments)

Comment: One important note: since you are trying to find the maxima/minima in a closed interval, do not forget to check the boundary points.

Comment: @Lakshay Garg Yes, but it is subject of convention for every specific problem  - should we account for boundary points as true extremums or not.

Comment: So, after finding roots ``r1`` and ``r2``, I plug both of them into the second derivative, and if the sign is negative, its a min, sign is positive, its a max?

Comment: Vice versa - **max for negative** second derivative value, min for positive.  And for y''=0 -  saddle point (like y=x^3 in x=0)

Comment: @MBo OP says "local min/max on the interval `[a, b]`". I interpret this as "find the minimum and maximum value of the function `f : [a, b] -> R`". I guess it makes sense to check the boundaries if this is the correct interpretation.